# AWS Cloudfront returns 403 but S3 returns 200

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have an S3 bucket that is **public** and I am currently using it to serve files on a web application. However, for performance and cost improvements I'm working on setting up AWS Cloudfront to serve the files.

The setup instructions are pretty simple so I kept all the defaults and selected the bucket that I would like to serve with Cloudfront. The origin is setup like an API `bucket`.s3.amazon.com.

If I put a url with the cloudfront domain into a browser I get a **403**
`uniqueid.cloudfront.net/visual/filename.jpg`

If I put the S3 url into a browser it works
`bucket-name.s3.amazon.com`

Most troubleshooting forums say to check the S3 policy but its clearly a Cloudfront issue rather than an S3 Policy issue. Some forums say I need to setup the Cloudfront domain with my DNS provider as a CNAME record but I assumed that was only if I was serving my website from Cloudfront which I am not.

Any ideas why I'm getting a 403?

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer: [AWS CloudFront access denied to S3 bucket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42251745/aws-cloudfront-access-denied-to-s3-bucket?rq=1)

Specifically:
Created an Amazon CloudFront web distribution:

- Origin Domain Name: Selected my S3 bucket from the list
- Restrict Bucket Access: Yes
- Origin Access Identity: Create a New Identity
- Grant Read Permissions on Bucket: Yes, Update Bucket Policy

Previously I had Restrict Bucket Access set to No which I thought would actually make the permissions less strict so it would work. However, by selecting Yes you can ensure that only your cloudfront URLs are used to access the bucket assets.

Comment: You're correct in a way but in description you mentioned that you're accessing the same url using s3 link directly , you can only access it on browser if it's public so I believe some of your objects were public and some were not , now that you have OAI in place, CloudFront can access it all.