# AccessDenied on files uploaded from Django to private S3 bucket with Cloudfront

Tags: django, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I'm an AWS noob setting up a hobby site using Django and Wagtail CMS. I followed [this guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nzLMA9WZqMM) to connecting an S3 bucket with django-storages. I then added Cloudfront to my bucket, and everything works as expected: I'm able to upload images from Wagtail to my S3 bucket and can see that they are served through Cloudfront.

However, the guide I followed turned off *Block all public access* on this bucket, which I've read is bad security practice. For that reason, I would like to set up Cloudfront so that my bucket is private and my Django media files are only accessible through Cloudfront, not S3. I tried turning *Block all public access* back on, and adding this bucket policy:

```
            "Sid": "2",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity XXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-s3-bucket/*"
```

The problem I'm encountering is that when I have *Block all public access* turned on, I receive `AccessDenied` messages on all my files. I can still upload new images and view them as stored in my AWS console. But I get `AccessDenied` if I try to view them at their CloudFront or S3 URLs.

What policies do I need to fix so that I can upload to my private S3 bucket from Django, but only allow those images to be viewable through CloudFront?

---

Update 1 for noob confusion: Realized I don't really understand how CDNs work and am perhaps confused about caching. Hopefully my edited question is clearer.

Update 2: [Here's a screenshot of my CloudFront distribution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RShgj.png) and a [screenshot of origins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSxAx.png).

**Update 3 (Possible solution):** I seem to have this working after making a change to my bucket policy statements. When I [created the OAI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-restricting-access-to-s3.html), I chose *Yes, update the bucket policy*, which added the OAI to `my-s3-bucket`. That policy was appended as a second statement to the original one made following the tutorial I linked above. My entire policy looked like this:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1620442091089",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1620442087873",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-s3-bucket/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "2",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity XXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-s3-bucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

**I removed the original, top statement and left the new OAI CloudFront statement in place. My S3 bucket is now private and I no longer receive `AccessDenied` on CloudFront URLs.**

Does anyone know if conflicting statements can have this effect? Or is it just a coincidence that the issue resolved after removing the original one?

Comment: Can you show us some screenshots of your CloudFront configuration?

Comment: @jellycsc yes I can do that. What sections of the console would be helpful?

Comment: origins in the Cloudfront distribution

Comment: Have you configured [OAI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-restricting-access-to-s3.html)?

Comment: @jellycsc well, I think I did? I thought that's what the bucket policy I pasted in my question was. Giving the CloudFront OAI read access to the bucket.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AWS CloudFront access denied to S3 bucket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42251745/aws-cloudfront-access-denied-to-s3-bucket)

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat thanks for finding that. I read through all the solutions but none of them seemed to work for me, although the symptom is almost identical.